# Xamarin Timer Being Created Multiple Times

Tags: xamarin, timer

I am struggling with my Xamarin Timer implementation and I was hoping someone could explain some of the behaviour I am seeing.

My application has a background service which is running and start from a Broadcast receiver ActionBootComplete.  Relevant code below.

```
{Android.App.Application.Context.StartService( new Intent( Android.App.Application.Context, typeof( UDPService ) ) ); }

{Android.App.Application.Context.BindService( udpServiceIntent, udpServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate );}
```

On My Main Activity I have a timer which is essentially a Health check timer that send an online message to our service.  The timer interval is customisable with the default value being event 15 seconds.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Health Check Timer
    /// </summary>
    System.Timers.Timer m_healthCheckTimer;
```

In the OnCreate Method I initialise and start the timer as per the below :-

```
        m_healthCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(m_healthPingInterval * 1000);

        m_healthCheckTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(m_healthCheck_Elapsed);

        m_healthCheckTimer.Start();
```

When the Timer elapses I fire the following code with some just being for debugging :-

```
 void m_healthCheck_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {

        try {

            LogFile.WriteInputLog(string.Format("Health Check Time Elapsed - Count  {0}", m_healthCounter), "Manager");

            m_healthCounter++;

            var nextValidPingString = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( m_healthPingInterval ) ) ;

            HealthCheckin(string.Format("{0} - Next Send Time {1}", "Main Activity Update Timer", nextValidPingString));

        } catch { }

    }
```

Essentially what I am seeing is the timer works perfectly for a time period, could be hours, could be days then I notice that the timer fires multiple times.  Inside the Log Files I will see 2+ counter instances incrementing seperately.  So Health Check 100 / 101 / 102 and mixed in with the logging may be Health Check 200 / 201 / 202.

My assumption is when the app is going into the background and then foreground, my Main Activity is being recreated which is creating a second instance of the timer.

I think the best way forward is to move the Timer to the Background service but for my own knowledge, I would like to know in my current scenario what could be done.

I cant seem to find an event that I can override that tells me the my Main Activity is being "recreated" so I could stop the original Timer or a method to override when the Main Activity is being disposed of to do the same sort of cleanup.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel.

Comment: Take a look at the Actvity lifecycle chart : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity OnCreate vs. OnResume vs. OnRestart ...

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions sounds right, and if that is the case then you need to stop the timer in `OnDestroy` method, you can dispose it there that sounds like the most appropriate thing to do:

```
m_healthCounter.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), it will only be executed once in the OnCreate method, unless the program is killed.

- First, you need to check if another timer is created in the program or the program appears to reopen the Activity.
- Second, in the OnDestroy method of the program, the timer is cleared.

  ```
  protected override void OnDestroy()
  {
      base.OnDestroy();
      if (null != m_healthCheckTimer)
      {
         m_healthCheckTimer.Dispose();
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, when creating a timer in OnCreate, determine if a timer
  already exists and then create it.

  ```
  if (null == m_healthCheckTimer){

     m_healthCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(m_healthPingInterval * 1000);

     m_healthCheckTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(m_healthCheck_Elapsed);

     m_healthCheckTimer.Start();
   }
  ```